# VS11 beta on main machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm currently using VS11 beta in a VM but its far to slow and it has crashed. But I was also installed under windows 8 which i found slow so i'm not sure if the speed problems is related to windows8+running in VM or if the produce is also slower.

Is VS11 beta stable on windows7? Does it crash often? (it crashed multiple times for me under windows8 in a vm). Will i have problems developing .NET 2-3.5? Can i have a duel install with 2010 + 11beta?

What should i know before installing the beta on my main machine?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be very stable.

Personally, I've been using it on Windows 7 for quite a while now (from pre-beta) and have had zero crashes.  I've also used it in Windows 8 and haven't seen any speed issues (both bootable VHD and a VirtualBox VM).  Your experience may be different.

You can run VS2010 and VS11 side by side.  If you have VS2010 SP1 installed projects can be round-tripped so that after you upgrade the project in VS11 it will still work in VS2010.

Working on .NET 2.0 and above is supported.